# html5 element doesn't take space and overflows on the next section

Tags: css, html

I want to make a resume page. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ohadpartuck/jp4LH/) is a jsfiddle

It looks like this:

```
<section class="ResumeItem">
    <header class="ResumeContentTitle" id="ResumeKnowledgeHeader">
         <p>Professional Knowledge</p>
    </header>
    <section>
         <section class="skills">
                        <header>
                            <h3>Strong Skills</h3>
                        </header>
                        <ul>
                            <li>PHP</li>
                            <li>jQuery</li>
                            <li>SQL</li>
                            <li>Ajax</li>
                            <li>HTML</li>
                            <li>CSS</li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>

                    <section id="ResumeKnowledge" class="ResumeContentText">

                        <ul>
                            <li>PHP </li>
                            <li>another item </li>
                            <li>another item </li>
                            <li>another item </li>
                            <li>another item </li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
</section>
<section class="ResumeItem">
                    <header class="ResumeContentTitle" id="ResumeKnowledgeHeader">
                        <p>Professional Knowledge</p>
                    </header>
</section>
```

​

the thing is that the ul li doesn't take "space". The next section considers only the id="ResumeKnowledge" section.

```
I tried:

.skills ul li{
    overflow: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is.

Comment: Your question is far from clear... What is the end effect you'd like to achieve? `it doesn't take space` is not descriptive enough.  If it *did* take space, what would you want it to look like?  This will not only help you in your own debugging, but ours as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the section is floating, so it is sitting outside of the DOM.  Adding a clear fixes the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/jp4LH/7/

I just added `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after the section

Comment: thanks, I'm a noobie... Stupid questions, I know.. thank god for stackoverflow..

Comment: noob questions are always welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the floating item outside of the DOM. The earlier answer is correct or you can add:
    section.ResumeItem{
        clear:both;
    }
if you want to keep the 2 columns floating beside each other.

Comment: yep, I threw in a quick edit to make them float side by side.  I thought throwing the div in the markup would make it clearer where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the inner `section` with class `skills` is floated, so the outer `section` collapses. One fix is to create a new [block formatting context](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/), which can be done by adding

```
overflow: hidden
```

to the outer section. Creating a new block formatting context like this forces the outer `section` to fully contain all the inner floating elements.